# solanaWeb3 : with only js Make a transaction , Require js, simple js

Tags: web3.js, transaction, solana-pay

I am trying  to make  a simple  transaction, I have  created  an app that connects to wallent , send to another wallet, I have the public key

```
const merchant = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey('somewallet96b4y1UPm9xuZ68rq5EWskVnbaddress');
const customer = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(wallet.publicKey.toString());
```

This is my code that I am trying  to make a transaction , what  I am missing  ?

```
    async function establishConnection(cluster = 'devnet') {
        const endpoint = solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl(cluster);
        const connection = new Connection(endpoint, 'confirmed');
        const version = await connection.getVersion();
        console.log('Connection to cluster established:', endpoint, version);

        return connection;
    }

  async function processPayment(merchant, customer) {

        const SystemProgram = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram;
        const Transaction = solanaWeb3.Transaction;
   
      const connection = await establishConnection();
    
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: customer,
                toPubkey: merchant,
                lamports: 10,
            });
```

I also tried another ways  but getting  errors

```
 solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [customer]);
```

Please help to find  the  flow  what I need to make a basic transaction from one to another.

Again I am using simple js where I can't run npm install and  anything else

Thank's  in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glace and without knowing the specific error youre encountering it's hard to say but you could try making sure you're passing in PublicKey instances into the transaction and not just strings.

try:

```
const merchantPub = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(merchant)
const customerPub = new solanaweb3.PublicKey(customer)
```

and then use those in for the toPubkey and fromPubkey.

And remember to subtract the 5000 lamports network fee if the "from" wallet is paying the fee and youre sending the entire balance.

Comment: const SystemProgram = solanaWeb3.SystemProgram;
const Transaction = solanaWeb3.Transaction;
const merchant = new  solanaWeb3.PublicKey('exampleCRMsaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaEWskVnbt');
const customer = new 
 solanaWeb3.PublicKey('examplevw96b4y1UPm9xuZ68rq5aaaaaaaaaEWskVnbt');
const connection = await establishConnection();
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({fromPubkey: customer, toPubkey: merchant, lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,}) );
let { blockhash } = connection.getRecentBlockhash();
 transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

Comment: transaction.feePayer = customer;
      await  solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, customer);

Comment: Above is my  full code  and I can't get my issues  ,errors are different , Can you please post an  answer with example , do 1,2,3 steps and you will have the transaction ?

Comment: I'm on mobile right sry but I think sendAndConfirmTransaction expects an array of signers, heres what mine normally look like: await sendAndConfirmTransaction( connection, transaction, [signer or signers])

Comment: I tried , this is another issue, in publicKey should have incide  privateKey object but it does not have , how I can have that private key ?

Comment: ` const feePayerIndex = uniqueMetas.findIndex(x => {
       return x.pubkey.equals(feePayer);
     });`

This is an error point I am getting , 
``index.iife.js:12887 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: x.pubkey.equals is not a function```